# Como listar produtos de um só restaurante?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Cadastrei meus produtos em um determinado restaurante.
Sendo Restaurante(1) e Produtos(N), tenho vários produtos cadastrados em um restaurante.

Como faço para listar esses produtos por cada restaurante?

Essa é a Action padrão:

```
public ActionResult Cardapio()
    {

        return View(db.Produtos.ToList());
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu faria assim:

```
public ActionResult Cardapio(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    var restaurante = db.Restaurantes
                        .Include(r => r.Produtos)
                        .FirstOrDefault(r => r.RestauranteId == id);

    if (restaurante == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    return View(restaurante.Produtos.ToList());
}
```

Uso:

```
http://localhost:porta/Restaurantes/Cardapio/1
```

Onde 1 é o Id do Restaurante.

Links:

```
@Html.ActionLink"Cardápio", "Cardapio", "Restaurantes", new { id = Model.RestauranteId })
```

Ou ainda:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Cardapio", "Restaurantes", new { id = Model.RestauranteId })">Ver Cardápio</a>
```

Comment: A lógica que usou é a que eu precisava mesmo! Porém meu id lá em cima está nulo. Preciso procurar ver o que é isso.

Comment: Pois eu acesso uma lista de restaurante, e nela clico nos detalhes, e dos detalhes vou pro cardápio dele. Sabe me dizer se há algum tipo de erro nesse caminho?

Comment: Use assim: http://localhost:porta/Restaurantes/Cardapio/1

Comment: No detalhamento: `@Html.ActionLink("Cardápio", "Cardapio", "Restaurantes", new { id = Model.RestauranteId })`. Se foi o que entendi.

Comment: Nossa, verdade! haha
Um erro que eu já havia cometido antes no início do projeto. Muito obrigado, Cigano! =D

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, quando usamos o Include ele faz um JOIN na query que vai para o banco certo, mas como isso fica quando é usado o FirstOfDefault ? ele gera uma lista de Produtos com apenas um Restaurantes?

Comment: @GOKUSSJGod Exato. Traz um restaurante com todos os seus produtos, como carga antecipada (*join*).